# Comparar dos fechas y dos hora en JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Hola amigos quiero comparar dos horas uno que es valor obtenido de un id, y el otro construido con la hora actual.

Y dos fecha tambien uno que es valor obtenido de un id, y el otro construido con la fecha actual donde:

```
var HoraActual = $('input:text[id=COMD_FECHA]').val();//=> 10:04 AM

var FechaActual = $('input:text[id=COMD_FECHA_ATENCION]').val();//=> 09/10/2018

var fa = fe + "/" + (f.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + f.getFullYear();//=> 09/10/2018

var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;//=> 10:04 AM

var HoraActual = $('input:text[id=COMD_FECHA]').val();
var FechaActual = $('input:text[id=COMD_FECHA_ATENCION]').val();
var f = new Date();
var fe = "";
if (f.getDate() < 10) {
    fe = "0" + f.getDate();
} else {
    fe = f.getDate();
}
var fa = fe + "/" + (f.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + f.getFullYear();
var hours = f.getHours();
var minutes = f.getMinutes();
var ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
hours = hours % 12;
hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
var strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;

if (FechaActual >== fa && HoraActual >== strTime ) {
    alert("Fecha y Hora actual es mayor");
}
else {
    alert("no son iguales");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Te recomiendo que uses Moment
`< script src="https://unpkg.com/moment" />
< script>
 moment.now() > moment(2016-11-23); //Regresa un boolean
</script>`

Donde moment.Now es tu fecha actual y en el segundo moment(Fecha_a_comparar) le pasas la fecha que obtienes de tus inputs.
saludos!

Answer (score 0):

El siguiente ejemplo te toma la fecha actual y la fecha obtenida del input time y date la inserta en otro objeto Date. separando la hora para insertarla con **setHours** y **setMinutes**.
en **setDate** le agregamos un día más por cuestiones de diferencia con el objeto Date y el input date.

```
var fecha_actual = new Date();
var timeArray = $('#hora').val().split(":");
var fecha_input = new Date($('#fecha').val());
fecha_input.setDate(fecha_input.getDate()+1);
fecha_input.setHours(timeArray[0]);

fecha_input.setMinutes(timeArray[1]);

if(fecha_actual > fecha_input){
  console.log("Fecha actual es mayor");
}else{
  console.log("Fecha actual es menor");
}
console.log(fecha_actual,fecha_input);
```